# Javascript: when does the scope chain created?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I heard two kinds of saying:

### When function is defined:

- In book `Professional Javascript for Web Developers, 3rd Edition`, in the `Chapter 7: Function Expressions` Closures parts:

> **When compare() is defined, its scope chain is
> created**, preloaded with the global variable object, and saved to the internal [[Scope]] property.
> When the function is called, an execution context is created and its scope chain is built up by
> copying the objects in the function’s [[Scope]] property.

**it's said the scope chain is created when the function id defined**.

### When function is called:

- In this article: [What is the Execution Context & Stack in JavaScript?](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/):

> So we now know that everytime a function is called, a new execution context is created. However, inside the JavaScript interpreter, every call to an execution context has 2 stages:

- Creation Stage [when the function is called, but before it executes any code inside]:

  - Create variables, functions and arguments.
  - **Create the Scope Chain**.
  - Determine the value of "this".
- Activation / Code Execution Stage:

  - Assign values, references to functions and interpret / execute code.

**it's said the scope chain is created when the function is called**.

So which is right ?

Comment: Forget what books say, read the specification: [Executable Code and Execution Contexts](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10). The second is reasonably accurate, however the [sequence is incorrect](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3), the *this* binding is established **first**. There is an excellent article on entering an execution context in the [comp.lang.javascript FAQ notes](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc).

Comment: Note that the article referenced is based on ECMA-262 ed 3, not the current ES5, but it's still good reading.

Answer (score 0):

Functions have an internal [[Scope]] property which is set to the scope where the function is defined in, *when it is defined*.

That scope is then part of the scope chain, together with the new scope created when the function is executed.